# Notation and countable of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Hi I am confused on some notation. I am trying to show that $\mathbb{Z}^{3} \cup \mathbb{Z}^{7}$ is countable. but I am not sure what the superscript means.

is $\mathbb{Z}^{3}=\{0,1,2\}$?

and if so wouldn't I simply have that there union is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} which has 7 elements, and so is countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^n$ denotes the **[$n$-fold Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)**. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}^2=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of *ordered pairs of integers*, so e.g. $(1, 37)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

In particular, $\mathbb{Z}^n$ looks infinitely bigger than $\mathbb{Z}$! But - perhaps surprisingly - they have the same cardinality. This exercise is basically asking about this:

- Show that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable, for every $n$.
- Show that the union of two countable sets is countable.

---

An important caveat: although $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is countable for each $n$, the set $\mathbb{Z}^\omega$ of infinite sequences of integers is **uncountable**, the reason being that it is much bigger than the "union" (*direct limit* is a better term to use here) of the $\mathbb{Z}^n$s (no infinite sequence of integers "comes from" any $\mathbb{Z}^n$). However, the set $\bigoplus_\omega\mathbb{Z}$ of infinite sequences of integers *all but finitely many of whose terms are zero* is countable.

Answer (score 0):

The notations are indeed confusing without further explanations. $\mathbb{Z}_3$ denotes sometimes the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, which may be represented by $\{0,1,2\}$. Usually, however, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ denotes the $3$-adic integers. In case of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ the notations is clear: it means $$\mathbb{Z}^3=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}.$$
Of course, both $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are countable, whereas the $3$-adic integers are *not* countable.